# specify user id when creating user in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I'm investigating a migration process from a legacy system into keycloak. Based on some of the ideas here: https://github.com/Smartling/keycloak-user-migration-provider we're looking to create user accounts in keycloak at the point of login by looking up user credentials from some dedicated endpoints on our legacy system.

As part of this, I need the user ID to remain the same as it was in the legacy system.

**Is it possible to create a user with a specified ID rather than relying on keycloak to auto-generate it?**

Comment: I've got as far as this CLI command kcadm.sh create users -r master -s username=myusername -s id=myid. But it is still autogenerating the id.

Answer (score 19):

Running into this issue when attempting to create users via the API, I looked into the code for the users service. It looks like it is currently not possible to set the user id due to how the user is created.

From the code in https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java specifically on line https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/7cfe6addf01676939206e034a87c791460031032/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java#L115 the user is first created using the username, then updated. I believe id is not an updatable field. Thus it is not currently possible.

Comment: I can confirm that setting the id for new users is not possible with the latest Keycloak server and client, even though the keycloak discussion group suggests that it were: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/rest-api-create-user-no-user-identifier-in-response/1964/2 – the id is ignored and a new UUID is generated

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question but you can actually import users with specific IDs if you use the [partial import endpoint](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_post_adminrealmsrealmpartialimport) and fill only the "users" attribute.

Regards,

LL

Answer (score -2):

Checking the api I see it is now possible to add an optional "id" field in the userRepresentation object that you pass to create a new user in keycloak.

Find more information here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation

Comment: Yes, but it looks like the value is ignored during user creation and a new id is generated regardless

Comment: Above link doesn't work anyway.